# prevent writes to nodes that don't exist firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a interesting firebase database problem. I'm going to walk you through the steps of how it comes about.

step 1: There is a node posted by user A

```
      "20180104" : {
    "-L2DNnIkER8XaBOI4n9l" : {
      "ImageName" : "EaWpwOXjmFsVatbkBM6V1307.jpg",
      "favoriteCount" : 12,
      "fileURL" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/...",
      "viewCount" : 20,
      "reportCount" : 2,
      "setID" : "-L2DNknqYN0IzTUN6pe-",
      "thumbFileUrl" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/...",
      "user" : "uid"
    },
    "-ABCDnIkER8XaBOI4n9l" : {
      "ImageName" : "EaWpwOXjmFsVatbkBM6V1307.jpg",
      "favoriteCount" : 3,
      "fileURL" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/...",
      "viewCount" : 8,
      "reportCount" : 2,
      "setID" : "-L2DNknqYN0IzTUN6pe-",
      "thumbFileUrl" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/...",
      "user" : "uid"
    },
```

step2: User B pulls this information off firebase.. Now they have the JSON locally in the app.

step3: User A deletes the second image key from the node in firebase.

Step4: the resulting JSON in firebase is:

```
          "20180104" : {
    "-L2DNnIkER8XaBOI4n9l" : {
      "ImageName" : "EaWpwOXjmFsVatbkBM6V1307.jpg",
      "favoriteCount" : 12,
      "fileURL" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/...",
      "viewCount" : 20,
      "reportCount" : 2,
      "setID" : "-L2DNknqYN0IzTUN6pe-",
      "thumbFileUrl" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/...",
      "user" : "uid"
    }, 
    // second node is now deleted
```

step5: Now user A decides to "like" that second photo, resulting in a write to the database.

step 6: Our resulting database in firebase:

```
          "20180104" : {
    "-L2DNnIkER8XaBOI4n9l" : {
      "ImageName" : "EaWpwOXjmFsVatbkBM6V1307.jpg",
      "favoriteCount" : 12,
      "fileURL" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/...",
      "viewCount" : 20,
      "reportCount" : 2,
      "setID" : "-L2DNknqYN0IzTUN6pe-",
      "thumbFileUrl" : "https://storage.googleapis.com/...",
      "user" : "uid"
    },
    "-ABCDnIkER8XaBOI4n9l" : {
      "favoritecount": 13
      // now we have corrupted data :(
    }
```

I want to prevent that final write in step 6. security rules side but can't seem to figure out how they work. say ".. if the parent key doesn't exist, don't write to it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your pic keys are not duplicated like they are in your example, you can prevent a write from occurring to a node which doesn't already exist like this:

```
"picDirectory" {
    "$picID": {
       ".write": "data.exists()"
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data).

Comment: oops, they actually aren't duplicated. I fixed it in the Question

Comment: Ok, for me it worked the way I needed if I took out the "!", So I wanted to write only if previous data existed.

Answer (score 0):

You universal id's are actually duplicated, i.e. `-L2DNnIkER8XaBOI4n9l` is the exact same key. The image is also the exact same image. It seems like you would have a unique key per image. Once you fix that, use transactions to handle shared counters such as likes or starts.

[Save data as transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

> For instance, in the example social blogging app, you could allow
>   users to star and unstar posts and keep track of how many stars a post
>   has received as follows:
>
> ```
> function toggleStar(postRef, uid) {
>   postRef.transaction(function(post) {
>     if (post) {
>       if (post.stars && post.stars[uid]) {
>         post.starCount--;
>         post.stars[uid] = null;
>       } else {
>         post.starCount++;
>         if (!post.stars) {
>           post.stars = {};
>         }
>         post.stars[uid] = true;
>       }
>     }
>     return post;
>   });
> }
> ```
>
> Using a transaction prevents star counts from being incorrect if
>   multiple users star the same post at the same time or the client had
>   stale data. If the transaction is rejected, the server returns the
>   current value to the client, which runs the transaction again with the
>   updated value. This repeats until the transaction is accepted or you
>   abort the transaction.

Comment: oops, they actually aren't the same images, I'll fix that. And I am doing a transaction on my side but it just still writes that other node